# Executing unzip command from Groovy

Tags: shell, groovy

I'm trying to run the unzip shell command from within Groovy.

I'm running the command

```
"unzip ~/Documents/myFile.txt.zip -d ~/Documents/".execute()
```

but it's not working.  When I copy the exact command into my terminal it works.  How can I do this from groovy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `~` as far as Groovy is concerned; use an actual path.

```
groovy:000> p = "ls -CF /Users/Dave".execute()
===> java.lang.UNIXProcess@2603826d
groovy:000> p.waitFor()
===> 0
groovy:000> p.in.text
===> Desktop/       Movies/         bin/
Documents/      Music/          node_modules/
Downloads/      Pictures/
Dropbox/        Public/     
Library/        ScreenshotOnFail/
```

You can always use `System.getProperty("user.home")`, e.g.,

```
p = "ls -CF ${System.getProperty('user.home')}".execute()
```

Comment: Simple solution that I've been banging my head against for a while. Thanks!

Comment: @CaseyPatton Note that `p.err.text` would show you the error message regarding the unknown directory.